# What hook should be used to run script when combinations tab on product edit page is loaded

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I am working on a new module for prestashop 1.5
And I need to add a line of html code to 'combinations' tab on product edit page.
I couldn't find any specific hooks in template/controllers/products/combinations.tpl
So I decided to add this line dynamically, using jQuery.

As a temporary solution, I used displayAdminProductsExtra hook. And I have a script inside included .tpl, that hides extra tab on the left and adds the reuired line to 'combinations' tab.

Obviously, this is not the best solution. 
First of all, it takes 1-2 seconds to load the extra tab contents, so the tab on the left is hidden with delay. Second, this way just doesn't look right.

So my question is: what would be the best way to run a script when 'combinations' tab is loaded?

If there is any better way to add a line of html code to 'combinations' tab, it would be even better:)

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed add html to combinations tab by overriding its template.

To do so, you will have to create in your module a file:
modules/your_module/override/controllers/admin/templates/products/combinations.tpl

In this file copy the following code:

```
{include file="controllers/products/combinations.tpl"}

// Add here your html code
<p style="color:red;text-align:center;">Add a text after the form</p>
```

Unfortunatly, when people will install your module, this file won't be copied automatically by Prestashop to the location where it needs to be to be taken care of.

To copy this file, you will have to add in your install function the code available in this topic :
http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/269657-resolu-overrider-template-admin-depuis-un-module/?p=1349110